# Limit of square root

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, parametric

Can you help me to calculate this limit as '$a$' varies in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow +\infty} \sqrt{2x^2 + x + 1} - ax$$

Comment: can you also compute the limit for x->-inf please

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The limit of $x \to +\infty =$ limit of $\sqrt{2x^2}-ax$ which is $+\infty$ for $a<\sqrt{2}$.  $-\infty$ for $a>\sqrt{2}$ and $0$ for $a = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I understand as this is your first post, that you didn't do this, but your generally supposed to say what you've tried or if you don't know even where to start.

Comment: @Houston The limit isn't $0$ for $a=\sqrt2$. The $x$ term inside the square root is actually relevant. It's easier to see in an example like $\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}-x$, but it still happens in this case.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Thank you all very much, I'll add more information in my next question.

Answer (score 4):

By multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{2x^2+x+1}+ax$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+x+1}-ax}{1}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2x^2+x+1-a^2x^2}{\sqrt{2x^2+x+1}+ax}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^2(2-a^2)+x+1}{x\left(\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+a\right)}
\end{align*}

- If $a=\sqrt{2}$, then
  $$=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x\left(\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{2}\right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
- If $a=-\sqrt{2}$, then
  $$=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x\left(\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{2}\right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{2}}=\left[\frac{1}{0^+}\right]=+\infty$$
- If $a\neq \pm\sqrt{2}$, then $(2-a^2)\neq0$, so
  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^2(2-a^2)+x+1}{x\left(\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+a\right)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x(2-a^2)+1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+a}=\left[\frac{+\infty(2-a^2)+1}{\sqrt{2}+a}\right]=\pm\infty$$
  You can notice, that
- if $a<-\sqrt{2}$, then $(2-a^2)<0$ and $\sqrt{2}+a<0$, so the limit is equal to $+\infty$
- if $a\in(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, then $(2-a^2)>0$ and $\sqrt{2}+a>0$, so the limit is equal to $+\infty$
- if $a>\sqrt{2}$, then $(2-a^2)<0$ and $\sqrt{2}+a>0$, so the limit is equal to $-\infty$

Comment: Awesome answer. It would be perfect if you added the case $a = \sqrt{2}$ :)

Comment: @Turing:  the case $a=\sqrt2$ is already there

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I was sure sleeping while writing my comment, I did not notice it at all. Lol.

Comment: @Andrzej Kukla thank you very much, it was very nice of you <3.

Answer (score 1):

For $a=\sqrt{2}$, the limit calculation is more complicated.  $\sqrt{2x^2+x+1}=\sqrt{2}x\sqrt{1+\frac{x+1}{2x^2}}\approx\sqrt{2}x(1+\frac{1}{4x})$  Subtract $ax$ and get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ as the limit.

For $a\ne \sqrt{2}$, this calculation leads easily to $\infty$ as the limit for $a\lt\sqrt{2}$ and $-\infty$ for $a\gt \sqrt{2}$.